# Add a value to array inside loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

While I map all the links on a page that is contained in an array, I want to check if each of the links is inserted in this array and, if not, insert it.

I'm trying to use the code bellow without success because "foreach $arr" doesn't pass by in the new values.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');
$arr = array('http://www.domain.com');

foreach ($arr as $key => &$item) {

$html = file_get_html($item);

// Find category links
foreach($html->find('a[href^=http://www.domain.com/dep/]') as $element) { 
  if (!in_array($element->href, $arr))
    $arr[] = $element->href;
   }

}

print_r($arr);
```

Important: I need to search and add value in the original array, not in the copy (foreach).

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: please remove "&" from foreach

Comment: Hi! I edited the question to be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: You want to add to array href value that is not in array, don't you ?

Comment: exactly. But in the same moment I am using it to find new href values.

Comment: The variable `$item` contains the value of the current element of the array in each iteration. Since you defined `$arr` as an array of two strings, `$item` will be a string. When you write `$item[] = ...` you try to append an element to a string, not an array, and hence the error message.

Comment: @LeonardoValentinZeferino I've updated my answer due to your comment

Answer (score 1):

First of all

In `foreach ($arr as $key => &$item) {` every `$item` is a **STRING**. (As a warning told you). So you shouldn't use `$item[]` here.

Next pitfall: if you want to add new items to your `$arr` array symtax should be

```
$arr[] = $some_var;
```

But you shouldn't do this because every time you add items to `$arr`, this array increases and you iterate not over two elements array, but for example 3-elements or 4 elements. Do you expect this?

You should find new values, put them in some other array and then merge both arrays.
Or use @splash58 solution. It's even simplier.

Comment: exactly. The problem of @splash58 code is that the foreach $arr won't pass by the new values inserted in the $arr.